# How to post a C# List<Object> into Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, json.net

I am creating a simple card game app that can be played online with friends who join into a game through a randomly generated code.

I chose to structure my database in the following way.

```
{
  "GameRooms" : {
    "-MF23P_AMI--leAoWfh5" : {
      "Code" : "s1a5a2",
      "NumberOfSpoons" : 1,
      "Players" : {
        "-MF23Tz3c00FCkGgKeUy" : {
          "Name" : "player1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the FirebaseDatabase.Net NuGet package to interact with the database. I am able to add 1 player to the Game under the `Players` node, however, after that, I am unable to add any other players who join with the code.

This is the code where I create a game under the `GameRooms` node (`firebase` is my FirebaseClient object):

```
public async Task CreateRoomAsync(Game game, Player gameCreator)
{
    var gameSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(game, Formatting.None);
    await firebase.Child("GameRooms").PostAsync(gameSerialized);
    JoinRoomAsync(game.Code, gameCreator);
}
```

This is the problematic code that is supposed to put a player under the `Players` node. (This only works the first time.):

```
public async void JoinRoomAsync(string gameCode, Player newPlayer)
{
    string gameKey = "Error";
    try
    {
        // FirebaseException thrown at this line of code.
        gameKey = (await firebase.Child("GameRooms").OnceAsync<Game>()).Where(a => a.Object.Code == gameCode).FirstOrDefault().Key;

    }
    catch (FirebaseException e)
    {
        var innerException = e.InnerException.Message;
    }      

    await firebase.Child("GameRooms").Child(gameKey).Child("Players").PostAsync(newPlayer);

}
```

InnerException of FirebaseException:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Spoons.Models.Player]' 
because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change 
the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, 
not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. 
JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '-MEesAsT1nVWPSxzbf8a.Players.0', line 1, position 75.
```

I have been trying to figure out how to properly upload a C# List into the Firebase Realtime Database.

These are the `Game` and `Player` classes:

```
public class Game
    {
        int numberOfSpoons = 1;

        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfSpoons { get { return numberOfSpoons; } set { numberOfSpoons = value; } }

        Deck deck = new Deck();

        public Deck GameDeck 
        {
            get { return deck; }
            set { deck = value; } 
        }

        public List<Player> Players { get; set; } = new List<Player>();

        public Game(string gameCode) 
        {
            this.Code = gameCode;
        }
```

```
    public class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Player(string name) 
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
```

I have been working to fix this for a while but I have gotten nowhere. I would really appreciate any help or suggestions on how I can overcome this. Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: So, the error is really helpful,no? *To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change 
the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, 
not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. 
JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.*

Comment: @CoolBots I understood the error, i am just unsure about how I would make the changes in my code.

Comment: Is this string in your JSON: `"-MF23Tz3c00FCkGgKeUy"` some sort of ID? Is it dynamically generated?

Comment: @CoolBots Yes, it's dynamically generated by firebase when an object is posted onto the database.

Comment: @CoolBots It is also the Key that is used to access the contents under that node when retrieving data.

Answer (score 4):

You need a *wrapper type* - your JSON is not exactly a `List<Player>`. I can successfully deserialize your JSON data if I use the following wrapper instead of `List<Player>`:

```cs
public class PlayerCollection
{
    public Dictionary<string, Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

The reason for that is the JSON structure:

```
"Players" : {
        "-MF23Tz3c00FCkGgKeUy" : {
          "Name" : "player1"
        }
    }
```

The top-level `Players` here is the *root object* - in my case, `PlayerCollection`. However, what's inside is *still not a `List<Player>`* - there is an auto-generated `ID` - so it's more of a `Dictionary<string, Player>` - where the `string` is the ID, and the `{ "Name" : "player1" }` is the `Player` object.

So, back to the error you're receiving - I'm providing *a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.*

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I'm going to give this a try. Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: just tried this out and works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: @HarshDave awesome! Glad I could help!